# Laravel 4 if no fields are filled out return validation

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4

I have a large form that has a lot of select boxes. How can using Laravel 4 Validation setup to see if any fields or filled and if no fields are filled in return to the page and display an error?

I know how to set it up I just don't see anything in the documentation that would solve this issue.

```
   $input = [
    //my get inputs will be going here
];

$rules = array(
    //not sure if any rules for not filled are here?
);

$message = array(
    //do I need a custom validator? 
);


$validation = Validator::make($input, $rules, $message);                            

if($validation->fails()){
    return Redirect::to('login')->withErrors($validation)->withInput();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Takin into account the idea you describe you will surely love the Ardent package which does (among others) automatic model validation. It uses the Laravel 4 validation mechanics internally. Check it out here [Laravelbook/Ardent](https://github.com/laravelbook/ardent) Below is a short description taken from the linked github page.

> Ardent - the magic-dust-powered, wrist-friendly, one-stop solution to
>   all your dreary input sanitization boilerplates!
>
> Puns aside, input validation functionality can quickly become tedious
>   to write and maintain. Ardent deals away with these complexities by
>   providing helpers for automating many repetitive tasks.
>
> Ardent is not just great for input validation, though - it will help
>   you significantly reduce your Eloquent data model code. Ardent is
>   particularly useful if you find yourself wearily writing very similar
>   code time and again in multiple individual applications.
>
> For example, user registration or blog post submission is a common
>   coding requirement that you might want to implement in one application
>   and reuse again in other applications. With Ardent, you can write your
>   self-aware, smart models just once, then re-use them (with no or very
>   little modification) in other projects. Once you get used to this way
>   of doing things, you'll honestly wonder how you ever coped without
>   Ardent.
>
> No more repetitive brain strain injury for you!